# Gmail delete messages straight from inbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Aware that there's been a few questions about this over the years, but Google's documentation has changed, and methods etc. have changed.

The doc page appears to reference both Gmail.users.messages.delete and Gmail.users.Threads.delete, and I'm not sure how to tell which is the current one, beyond neither of them working when I change the script.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/delete

Aware that also, the recommendation is that trash is used. The Gscript that I've got to move all messages with a certain filter move to trash fine but I want that same script to dump them from trash too and I'd prefer, in this case, to bypass it entirely.

Have added the Gmail API service into the project, and also enabled the GmailAPI in my account.

So initially, I thought I'd trash it, and then remove from trash, thus:

```
function DeleteMail() { 
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:test');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
  }

  var threads2= GmailApp.search('in:trash subject:test')
  for (var p = 0; p < threads2.length; p++) {
    var thisid=threads2[p].getId();
      Gmail.users.messages.delete('me', threads2[p].thisid);
  }
}
```

I get the error: *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')*

So I altered the script so that it would bypass the trashing bit and just straight up remove it

```
function DeleteMail() { 
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:test');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thisId = threads[i].getId();
      Gmail.users.messages.delete('me', threads[i].thisId);
  }
```

and get the error: *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messages')*

Can anyone point me where I'm going wrong here please?

Comment: apologies, yes, lowercase.

Comment: I find `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove`

Comment: Also I find you need to use Advanced API?
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/delete

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, so how do I tell which is the most current update as the docs lead to both for the Gmail API.

Comment: @mplungjan Also, yeh, have added Gmail API into services and enabled GMail as instructed to add via the reference docs.

Comment: I see GUM.action:  Gmail.Users.Messages.action so I would start with the casing of your code

Comment: From your showing script, do you want to delete threads? Because in your script, the thread ID is used. If my understanding is correct, in this case, please use `Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", threads[i].getId())` instead of `Gmail.users.messages.delete('me', threads2[p].thisid)` and `Gmail.users.messages.delete('me', threads[i].thisId)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/delete) If you want to delete messages, it is required to retrieve the message ID instead of the thread ID. Please be careful about this.

Comment: If you want to delete messages, you can use `Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/batchDelete) By the way, if you want to delete threads retrieved by `GmailApp.search('subject:test')`, I think that the sample script might be `GmailApp.search('subject:test').forEach(e => Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", e.getId()))`.

Comment: Sorry. In this case, it seems that `GmailApp.search('subject:test').forEach(e => Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", e.getId()))` and `Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete({ ids: GmailApp.search('subject:test').map(e => e.getId()) }, "me")` can be also used.

Comment: @Tanaike So the situation is that there is a certain email source that I don't even want to see in deleted items, and it will just be a single message arriving in my email box, Would it be better to focus on messages in this case?

Comment: Thank you for repling. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What is `deleted items`? Are those threads or messages moved to the trashbox? And, do you want to delete the specific threads or messages in the trashbox?

Comment: If my understanding is correct and the threads you want to permanently delete have the common subject of `test` and those are in trash box, how about `GmailApp.search('in:trash subject:test').forEach(e => Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", e.getId()))` or `GmailApp.search('in:trash subject:test').forEach(e => Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", e.getId()))` or `Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete({ ids: GmailApp.search('in:trash subject:test').map(e => e.getId()) }, "me")`? If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Apologies @Tanaike - your English is great by the way - by 'deleted items' I meant 'Trash'. So, I'd like for a selected message to be deleted immediately when it arrives into my email to bypass trash so that I don't even have to see it. I realise that I may need to investigate triggers to make this work, but this is stage 1 :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I'd like for a selected message to be deleted immediately when it arrives into my email to bypass trash`, in this case, how about the following 2 patterns? 1. Use the time-driven trigger. In this case, you can see [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually). 2. Use "Method: users.watch" of Gmail API and pub/sub. In this case, you can see [the official document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). But, this might not be the main question in your current question.

Comment: By the way, when you use Google APIs with Advanced Google services, I think that the auto-completion of the script editor might be useful for understanding the method for using the API. [Ref (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/taking-advantage-of-auto-completion-of-script-editor-for-google-apps-script-be088a76cd86)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for the clarification. I think the problem here is that I don't know the Google environment, or JS, am coming form Python mostly. That said, I will need to eventually change the search term from 'test' to particular mails that are coming from particular people, but assume that's merely a syntax change.

Comment: @Tanaike I have tried just a one line script of ```GmailApp.search('in:trash subject:test').forEach(e => Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", e.getId()))``` and that appears to remove the email with the subject 'test' totally from my mail. So I just need to alter the search term so that it is from a certain sender. Would the next step to be set triggers?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion. I deeply apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike Hello. Just to clarify, your answer was the one that made it work for me. Your comments were absolutely useful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to delete certain messages directly without them having to go to trash.

#### Try:

```
function DeleteMail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"test"');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thisId = threads[i].getId();
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', thisId);
  }
}
```

#### Modifications:

- In your current code, in the subject, you have to enclose the actual subject in double quote (").
- Also changed the `Gmail.users.messages.delete('me', threads[i].thisId);` to `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', thisId);`.
- Set up with time driven trigger.

Comment: Let me know if this works or if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks @Logan. I'm beginning to think that I haven't set up the environment correctly, as I'm getting this error: "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to gmail.users.messages.delete failed with error: Requested entity was not found."

Comment: @FiddleDeDee Are you using the code I've shared? Try the .remove instead of delete. I have not encountered this error you are having.

Comment: Yeh, I commented all mine out and just pasted yours into the project and ran it. Could it be that the 'thisID var is asking for a thread ID and I'm referring to a message?

Comment: The error you are having says .delete which is not present in my code.

Comment: Good spot. I think I may start a new project and see what happens there, as that doesn't make any sense. I did a straight copy pasta and commented out all the old code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255953/discussion-between-fiddlededee-and-logan).

Answer (score 1):

**Delete email from inbox utilizing batch delete**

Adjust subject target as required.  BatchDelete should be a little fast than doing it one at a time.

```
function DeleteMail() {
  const idA = GmailApp.getInboxThreads().map(t => 
   t.getMessages().map(m => (m.getSubject() == "TEST") ? m.getId():"")).flat().filter(e => e);
  if (idA && idA.length > 0) {
    var request = { "ids": idA };
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  }
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thank you @Cooper. I didn't notice any massive delay with doing it one at a time, less than a second, but I appreciate the sentiment. It's a good learning exercise. Can you offer an explanation why the google ref uses all lower case, and yet the code requires camel? Or is that just my inexperience with Javascript.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Gmail.Users.Messages vs. gmail.users.messages Does GScript care?

Comment: Oh sorry  did I have lower case there?  I didn't see that